# Pointer Alignment of Function Arguments in C++17

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I see C++17 introduce aligned new-expressions with `std::align_val_t` for objects requiring greater alignment than naturally provided by `new`. This is great, but got me thinking:

**Why is pointer alignment not part of pointer types?**

For instance:

```
long foo(long *x) {
  return *x; // here, the compiler do an aligned load
             // correct as (long*) is expected to be aligned
}
```

Will assume the pointer is aligned on 64 bits (on my machine).
But the compiler do not warn me if I do the following:

```
long bar(char *x) {
  return foo((long*) x); // here, the compiler do an aligned load, risky!
}

long pop(char *z) {
  return bar(z + 1); // here, the compiler do an aligned load too!
}
```

I managed to get a warning by passing a pointer to a field from a packed struct:

```
struct ugly {
  char x;
  long y;
} __attribute__((packed));

long kun(ugly *a) {
  return a->y; // here, the compiler do an unaligned load, correct!
}

long zip(ugly *a) {
  return foo(&a->y); // here, the compiler do an aligned load, incorrect!
                     // but warns me about it.
}
```

But why is it not an error, akin to `const_cast`?

*What does the standard says with regard to alignment?*

Are all compiler doing incorrect assumption, or is it undefined/implementation defined behavior to give an unaligned pointer to a function?

You can see them in action here: https://godbolt.org/g/9ddbiq

**Edit**: Fixed the code snippet, and provided a godblot link.

Comment: It probably is implementation specific (and UB). Alignment matters at the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) level, not only at the language level

Comment: Your example is not legal c++. It won't compile because can't assign a `void*` to a `long*` and you can't assign `3` to a `long*`. In addition, it appears you are trying to dereference a pointer set to the address of 3.

Comment: We really need a [mcve] for this question probably with a link to the example on https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 2):

> What does the standard says with regard to alignment?

That's simple: every object of type `T` which exists has the proper alignment.

If you use placement `new` and provide a pointer with insufficient alignment, UB results. If you replace the `new` allocator and provide a pointer with insufficient alignment for the type being allocated, UB results. If your `std::allocator<T>::allocate` returns a pointer that is not aligned appropriately to `T`, UB results. And so forth.

Undefined behavior doesn't require compilation failure.

Comment: And it is still UB even if the block is actually large enough to hold the object. Some platforms can deal with unaligned data (just with a severe performance hit, x86 for example), many others can't even do that and will fault on the attempt.

Comment: I see. So "packed" struct are the only way to create such incorrect object (using `new`) and that justify why it is not part of the standard.